# Python configuration in Windows - Module locations - pip vs Eclipse/Liclipse

Tags: python, windows, configuration, path, version

I'm trying to use pdfminer in Windows, and I am having a lot of issues with my Python configuration and library locations.

I seem to have multiple versions of Python installed, with multiple library locations.  When trying to run a simple pdfminer text extraction example, I get an error that it can't find chardet to import.

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\utils.py", line 13, in <module>
import chardet  # For str encoding detection in Py3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chardet'
```

Running pip install chardet reports:

```
Requirement already satisfied: chardet in c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages (3.0.4)
```

So, Liclipse is looking for its libraries in a different place than pip.

My eventual target is to bundle this up into an executable that I can deploy.  What's the best way to deal with this?  Should I set up a PYTHONPATH that includes both library locations?  Am I risking version conflicts?  Is there another alternative that makes more sense for a standalone solution?

And, what level do I need to point PYTHONPATH at?  Just the .../lib level, and it'll recurse below that?  I don't see it specified in the docs.

---

Edit:  I added PYTHONPATH to my environment variables, and then relaunched Liclipse.  I included the .../lib level of both locations.  No change in behavior.  Then, I went into the project properties and added both locations to the External Libraries tab.  Still the same error.

How do I sync where up Liclipse and pip expect to find the libraries?

---

Another edit:  When I add "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages" to the External Libraries tab I get an error when trying to access pip.get_installed_distributions().  When I don't have that in there, it runs fine.  My sys.path is:

```
['D:\\Users\\MyUser\\Documents\\LiClipse Workspace\\Parse TOC', 'D:\\Users\\MyUser\\Documents\\LiClipse Workspace\\Parse TOC', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\Lib', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\Lib', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\DLLs', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\python36.zip']
```

It appears right before the ...\python36.zip entry.  So, that looks to me like a probable version conflict?

Comment: how do you run your program? console? IDE?

Comment: If you plan on deploying this, use `venv`

Comment: In the IDE.  I'm implementing a parser, so I anticipate a lot of time in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure the best way to present this is to answer my own question.

The root of my problem was a conflict between the copy of Python installed as part of Visual Studio and the separate Python installation I ran a few days ago.

I think when I installed Visual Studio a year or two ago, I chose to add Python support, because I had considered learning it as a side project.  I had forgotten I had done that when I finally had an actual need for Python.  So, I installed it, again.

I found [this page](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-add-python-module-library-in-eclipse-pydev/) and went in and removed every reference to any version of Visual Studio in the Global area and from the project properties.  I removed Visual Studio from PYTHONPATH.  That appears to have cleared everything up.